# Launch local folder from XPSP2+ / IE8

Tags: security, internet-explorer, intranet

We've got an intranet which normally serves all info/documents that appl to the whiole company (employee handbooks, minutes, etc...)

Most of these work by having the web server parse a folder and present the files to the user.

The problem in this case is that the latest folder is restricted to cerain users. As Kerberos is not currently an option, I was planning to side-step the issue and just insert a link which opens up a UNC path:

file://\Server\SecureFolder\

I've just found out that since XPSP2 this hasn't been possible with standard HTML/JS.

Does anyone know of a nother way this can be done? It's internal so I've got a lot of control over the webserver (but domain config changes will have to be justified)

I'm wondering if there's something like .Net or an ActiveX [shudder] solution or similar?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the solution was to do it without Javascript and without the file://

The following works:

```
<a href="\\Server\Folder">Link</a>
```